# How can I access a variables value in a different program?

Tags: c, arrays, variables, encryption

I have 2 c programs, one encrypts some bytes in an array and the other decrypts them. I need some way to grab the encrypted bytes from the first program, so I can decrypt them in the second program.

How can I access the array holding the encrypted bytes from the first program? Any ideas?

Comment: Write to a file, or to a pipe?

Comment: The more sensible ways use a file or perhaps a pipe.  The less sensible ways use shared memory or message queues.  The ridiculous ways do things like run a debugger on the first program from within the second program.

Comment: The question is really how you would share data. That it is encrypted or not doesn't change anything.

Comment: The question is really how you would share data. That it is encrypted or not doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Maarten stated the The question is really how you would share data between apps. some would say writing to a file or pipes i might say sockets..  you may try this :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/586000/Networking-and-Socket-programming-tutorial-in-C